# How to use @TestConfiguration for avoiding src/test/java scanning?

Tags: spring-boot-test

According to [25.3.3. Excluding Test Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.0.M2/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-excluding-config) this capability exists:

> When placed on a top-level class, @TestConfiguration indicates that
>   *classes in src/test/java should not be picked up by scanning*

I created both `@Configuration FilledWithBeanTestConfig` and `@TestConfiguration DummyTestConfig` in the project's root path/package `src/test/java/com/example/mvctries/`. My `main` method-containing class is *on purpose* annotated with `@ComponentScan` just in order to accidentally pick `FilledWithBeanTestConfig`; about this situation Spring is specifically warning:

> If your application uses component scanning (for example, if you use
>   @SpringBootApplication or @ComponentScan), you may find top-level
>   configuration classes that you created only for specific tests
>   accidentally get picked up everywhere.

I used `@Import(DummyTestConfig.class)` in a `@WebMvcTest` annotated test class placed in `src/test/java/com/example/mvctries/controller/`; I was expecting for the `@Configuration FilledWithBeanTestConfig` to just be ignored but it wasn't. Moving `DummyTestConfig` to `src/test/java/com/example/mvctries/controller/` also didn't help.

What am I doing wrong when testing the way presented above this `src/test/java` scanning-ignore capability?
How should I properly use `@TestConfiguration` in order to use this `src/test/java` scanning-ignore capability?
How would I test this capability by using `@SpringBootApplication` component scanning only instead of *on purpose* scanning with `@ComponentScan`?

While the above questions might seem too many they are in fact another way of asking the following **one question**: how would one craft a project which to clearly prove how `@TestConfiguration` usage leads to *classes in src/test/java should not be picked up by scanning*.

**UPDATE**

Here's the example project: https://github.com/adrhc/spring-boot-test-checks.git; it's using port 8083 when running the application; better run the test class.

Comment: can you share a sample project? and explicitly mention what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 2):

`@ComponentScan` without `filter` property will always load all `@Configuration` classes. `@TestConfiguration` works only for that one annotated class and not for the whole package/directory.

It seems like an unfortunate formulation in the docs - it discusses usage of `@TestConfiguration` on **top level classes** inside `src/test/java` rather than on [the inner class of you test](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-rest-templates-test-utility).

In short: Never use `@ComponentScan` without `TypeExcludeFilter` - it will start loading everything for all your `SpringBootTest` tests and also for tests using slices - which beats the purpose of having slices in the first place.

Once you get rid of `@ComponentScan` (or once you add the mentioned filter):

- `@SpringBootTest` will load all `@Configuration` classes but will not load `@TestConfiguration` classes. `@TestConfiguration` classes can be picked when needed using `@Import`.
- Test slices like `@WebMvcTest` will not load any extra custom classes / configurations unless you instruct them with `@Import`. If all your tests with `@WebMvcTest` (or other slice) need additional configuration then you can easily create your own slice or alter the existing one using META-INF/spring.factories file (a separate topic though).

Answer (score 0):

When `@ComponentScan` is applied, then `excludeFilters` need to be added in order to avoid picking up `@TestConfiguration`s by accident:

```
@ComponentScan(value = { "my.base.package" }, excludeFilters = {
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = TypeExcludeFilter.class),
        @Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = AutoConfigurationExcludeFilter.class) })
public class BootTestConfig { }
```

For reference: Look at `@SpringBootApplication`; it defines `excludeFilters` on `@ComponentScan`.